# Perl strings inside system call to Java

Tags: java, perl, weka

I define array @ID at the beginning of the code. I do different things with this list of ids, and therefore I define `my $id;` at the beginning only (I `use strict; warnings`).

Maybe I simplified too much to ask the question, so it end up being unclear.

Both `$cv` and `$smo` are `$id` dependent and they are all perl strings. Like this:

```
.... 
for $id (@ID) { 

    $cv = $htotal{$id};
    $smo = $hsmote{$id};

    system('java -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -t Projects/proteins/$id_MSA/$id_.arff -x $cv -s 0 -p 1,2 -distribution \
        -F "weka.filters.MultiFilter -F \" weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove -R 7,9\" -F \" weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.RemoveType -T string\" \
        -F \"weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE -C 0 -K 5 -P $smo -S 1\"" -W weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -- -L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H 0 \
        > Projects/rbfs/$id.rbf');
}
...
```

To make sure there were no Weka errors, I tried, e.g. cv = 2, smo =100, id=P12345; and it worked fine, so it was an interpolation issue, as some of you mentioned.

From the solutions you've mentioned I tried double quotes + {} as @nlu suggested:

```
system('java [...] -t Projects/proteins/"${id}"_MSA/"${id}"_.arff -x "${cv}" -s 0 -p 1,2 -distribution [...]    -F \"weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE -C 0 -K 5 -P "${smo}" -S 1\"" [...] > Projects/rbfs/"${id}".rbf');
```

But didn't worked, did I write it wrong?

Same with this (replacing `system()` for ``  ) didn't work:

`java [...] -t Projects/150400_GSupdate/proteins/${id}_MSA/${id}.arff -x ${cv} -s 0 -p 1,2 [...] -F \"weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE -C 0 -K 5 -P ${smo} -S [...] > Projects/150400_GSupdate/rbfs/${id}.rbf`;

What finally has worked for me is string concatenation (as @Matt suggested) but I'm sure that all other options should be fine too, although don't know why not.

Comment: http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/interpolation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if the other variables are shell variables other than $id? If you want *just* $id to be substituted the easiest way is to just use string concatenation:

```
for $id (@ID) {
    system('java -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -t $PATH/proteins/$id_MSA/$id_.arff -x $cv -s 0 -p 1,2 -distribution \
        -F "weka.filters.MultiFilter -F \" weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove -R 7,9\" -F \" weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.RemoveType -T string\" \
        -F \"weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE -C 0 -K 5 -P $smo -S 1\"" -W weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -- -L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H 0 \
        > $PATH/rbfs/' . $id . '.rbf');
}
```

If you wanted all the $something to be treated as if they were perl variables probably the easiest way given you need to use " and \" inside the system string is to replace system() with the `` operator which basically does the same thing as system.

```
for $id (@ID) {
    `java -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -t $PATH/proteins/$id_MSA/$id_.arff -x $cv -s 0 -p 1,2 -distribution \
        -F "weka.filters.MultiFilter -F \" weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove -R 7,9\" -F \" weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.RemoveType -T string\" \
        -F \"weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE -C 0 -K 5 -P $smo -S 1\"" -W weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -- -L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H 0 \
        > $PATH/rbfs/$id.rbf`;
}
```

Comment: Also your for loop should be using a local variable so `for my $id (@ID) {}`. This is suggestive you haven't got  use strict; use warnings; at the top of your script which will help you out a lot in avoiding common problems. That or you are reusing $id from outside scope which isn't a good plan unless you have a good reason, which it doesn't look like you do.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function in Perl, like `system` in your case, you can use `interpolation` to have variables inside the strings substituted.

You need to pass the string in double quotes for this to happen, so first you have to replace your surrounding single quotes with double quotes.

Besides, for disambiguation of any variable names appearing in the string, you should write them like this:

```
"${id}"
```

to avoid confusing variable names like i.e. `id` and `idsomething`.

Documented here:
http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors